# Transaction Observer at App Start

Tags: xcode, swift, in-app-purchase

I understand implementing a transaction observer at time of app load is recommended. I am executing below line in viewDidLoad:

```
SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addTransactionObserver(self)
```

But this causes the app to ask for user's App Store credentials at app launch which is not the behaviour we would want. What is wrong?

Comment: probably you also create and start `SKProductsRequest` object, which actually asks user's credentials.

Comment: I only start SKProductsRequest when user initiates an IAP.

Comment: Sounds like you have unfinished transactions in the queue.

Comment: Chris: You are probably right. But once I log in, it should complete the trans and then be at rest, right? But it doesn't.